# Automatic sitemap generation

Tags: java, sitemap, google-search-appliance

We have recently installed a Google Search Appliance in order to power our internal search (via the Java API), and all seems to be well, however I have a question regarding 'automatic' site-map generation that I'm hoping you guys may know the answer to.

We are aware of the GSA's ability to auto-generate site maps for each of its collections, however this process is rather manual, and considering that we have around 10 regional sites that need to be updated as often as possible, its not ideal to have to log into the admin interface on a regular basis in order to export them to the site root where search engines can find them.

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any API support for this, at least none that I can find, so I was wondering if anyone had any ideas for a solution/workaround or, if all else fails, the best alternative.

At present I'm thinking that if we can get the full index back from the API in the form of a list, then we can write an XML file out using that the old fashioned way using a chronjob or similar, however this seems like a bit of a clumsy solution - any better ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the [GSA Admin Toolkit](http://code.google.com/p/gsa-admin-toolkit/), or simply write some code yourself which just logs in on the administration page and then uses that session to invoke the sitemap export URL (which is basically what the Admin Toolkit does).

Comment: Ahh, very nice, cant believe i didn't come across that while searching! Should hopefully get me most of the way.
Thanks!